# Manière idiomatique de dire que les gens malhonnêtes ont tendance à voir le mal partout

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique

J'écris un livre en ce moment, et un de mes personnages est un ancien voleur, arnaqueur et menteur qui s'est repenti (appelons le X).

Un autre personnage (appelons le Y) lui pose une question de façon totalement innocente, et X monte sur ses grands chevaux en pensant que la question adressée était pleine de sous-entendus sur son passé.

Je veux que Y rétorque à X que s'il a mal interprété sa question c'est à cause de son passé lourd en fautes qui lui fait voir le mal partout.

Comment dirait-on cela ? Y a t'il une formule idiomatique en français déjà existante ?

Une phrase du genre

> Seuls les voleurs pensent à comment protéger leur maison.

ou encore

> Les menteurs se méfient même des innocents.

Je ne sais pas si je suis assez claire, j'ai donc volontairement laissé beaucoup de contexte que je retirerais si nécessaire.

Comment: Bienvenue sur FLSE ! Pas de soucis pour le contexte, au contraire, il défini clairement le besoin, c'est juste ce qu'il faut (je n'ai malheureusement pas la réponse)

Comment: La seule expression qui me vient à l'esprit c'est *"être sur la défensive"*, même si c'est un peu éloigné du contexte. Néanmoins, suivi d'une phrase comme *"As-tu donc tant d'ennemis que tu peines à reconnaître tes amis ?"* (PS je ne suis pas écrivain :-), ça pourrait le faire.

Comment: @SteffX Perso, j'aime bien la proposition :)

Comment: @Random Merci. Alors je t'engage comme non-agent du non-écrivain que je suis ! Intéressé ? :-)

Comment: Peut-on savoir de quelle question il s'agissait ? Merci.

Comment: Pourquoi vouloir une formule idiomatique, qui pourrait faire un peu cliché, alors que tes deux exemples sont, je trouve, très pertinents ? Ainsi que la proposition de SteffX, qui sonne moins "expression" car ciblant directement l'interlocuteur par *as-tu*.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps à vrai dire je posais cette question par curiosité, pour savoir si une telle formule existait et si elle était évidente à placer, ou si je devais me contenter d'en trouver une moi même. Je vais donc au final utiliser ma propre formulation. Merci pour vos réponses !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quelques suggestions autour de "avoir l'esprit mal tourné", l'idée étant de sous-entendre que si X a l'esprit mal tourné ou voit le mal partout, c'est qu'il y a une explication... à chercher dans son passé.

> Y: — Ça, tu as vraiment l'esprit mal tourné...
>
> Y: — Tu as l'esprit mal tourné, en même temps ça ne m'étonne pas...
>
> Y: — Tu vois le mal partout, en même temps ça ne m'étonne pas...

On pourrait aussi imaginer quelque chose de plus direct comme

> Y: — Tiens, on dirait que j'ai touché un point sensible...

Ou alors, si X vient d'accuser explicitement Y de quelque chose dont X aurait bien pu être coupable lui-même :

> X: — Dis donc, tu es bien impertinent
>
> Y: — Ha ! Moi, impertinent ? C'est l'hôpital qui se moque de la charité ! / se fout de la charité !

Comment: Je pense qu'il n'existe pas de phrase idiomatique pour dire ce que je recherche, mais je trouve que ta proposition est la meilleure des trois, donc je vais l'accepter. Merci d'avoir répondu !

Comment: Merci. J'en ai ajouté quelques autres qui me sont venues plus tard.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility, more idiomatic : « Il faut être tordu pour penser que … » "tordu" here would refer to his dark past. Il faut être tordu pour être un arnaqueur.

Voir plus directement : "Il faut être malhonnête (comme toi) pour penser que/à …" Ton personnage pourrait dire aussi : "Il faut (vraiment) être un voyou / une crapule / un cravard pour interpréter ma question comme ça"

Comment: Ta proposition est pertinente mais ne correspond pas à ce que je recherche. Merci d'avoir répondu

Answer (score 2):

L'expression **déformation professionnelle** pourrait vous intéresser dans ce contexte.

La *déformation professionnelle* c'est lorqu'on voit les choses et/ou on y réfléchit de la même façon qu'au travail alors qu'on y est pas/plus.

Answer (score 1):

On a le proverbe *chat échaudé craint l'eau froide*, dans le sens que « d'une mésaventure naît un excès de prudence. » ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/chat_%C3%A9chaud%C3%A9_craint_l%E2%80%99eau_froide)) ; il n'est pas difficile d'associer le passé de cette personne à une mésaventure, mais son propos reflète-t-il un excès de prudence ? Je ne suis pas l'auteur.

---

Par ailleurs, on peut juger une personne (être trop) [*susceptible*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/susceptible) : « Qui est facilement blessé, offensé par des actes, des propos qu'il ressent comme hostiles, qui se vexe facilement. » (TLFi)

On pourrait aussi présumer de la réaction d'une personne qu'elle soit en train de (faire de la) *projection* : « Fait de projeter ses sentiments sur autrui » ([Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/projection/64230?q=projection#63508)) ; « Mécanisme de [défense](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/21571/mani%C3%A8re-idiomatique-de-dire-que-les-gens-malhonn%C3%AAtes-ont-tendance-%C3%A0-voir-le-mal#comment41525_21571) qui consiste à localiser chez autrui, de manière inconsciente, et pour s'en protéger, des idées, des affects perçus comme un danger par le moi. » ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/projection))

...*vu/à cause de son passé* (dans votre récit). Il peut y avoir association, ou non (dans la vie). L'idée de *mal interpréter* que vous avancez est parfaitement usuelle, et on peut présumer des raisons (que comme créatrice du personnage vous connaissez) qui expliquent ça. Mais à mon avis, respectueusement, vos deux exemples de phrase relèvent du sophisme, et il m'étonnerait qu'on ait élevé de telles idées en un quelconque adage qui puisse être utile ici.

Comment: "chat échaudé craint l'eau froide" c'est quand il est arrivé quelque chose de mal à quelqu'un, et que la personne se retrouve à avoir peur d'une situation qui ressemble mais est en fait inoffensive. Quel rapport avec ce que demande OP (quelqu'un qui a fait du mal par le passé et se projette maintenant sur les autres en pensant qu'eux aussi veulent faire du mal) ? Pour "susceptible" je ne comprend même pas comment c'est arrivé là, il n'y a pas d'explication (et ça me paraît franchement n'avoir aucun rapport avec la question).

Answer (score 1):

«Paranoïaque» «*tu es paranoïaque*» is the closest French word that describe it accurately.

«Ton/votre interpretation est emplie de paranoïa»

«Tu paranoye/ Paranoyer» (Incorrect, but largely used like [explained here](http://dictionnairedesverbesquimanquent.kamboo.com/paranoyer/))

«Arrête de me charier» or «Tu me charie» should be considered as well, as it refer to the mutual known past between X and Y. [Verbe charrier | Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/charrier/14822)

> ***Charrier:***
>
> *Idéologie qui charrie avec elle des utopies.*
>
> *Se moquer de quelqu'un.*

Answer (score 1):

Ce mécanisme est nommé [projection en psychanalyse](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(psychanalyse)). C'est un "mécanisme de défense" des paranoïaques. L'exemple le plus connu et celui de l'amant infidèle jaloux au sein d'un couple (l'amant infidèle soupçonne, voir accuse, l'autre membre du couple).

Sans utiliser le terme "projection psychanalytique" directement (c'est un peu perché), on peut utiliser le verbe **projeter** : les experts en psychanalyse apprécieront, les autres comprendront :

> **Mais non pas du tout ! Ne projettes pas (tes défauts ? / ton passé ?) sur moi...**

Les phrases proposées par OP, font aussi passer l'idée. Je penses qu'il est toujours possible de créer son propre idiome (loufoque, ou bien qui passera à la postérité ?). Quelques tentatives, parce que ça m'amuse d'essayer  :

> Il est compliqué de convaincre un singe qu'on ne volera pas sa banane
>
> Une pièce d'or sortant d'usine rendrait un faussaire suspicieux. / Tout œuvre d'art rendrait un faussaire suspicieux / Même un tableau de la sainte vierge rendrait un faussaire suspicieux
>
> Il n'est de plus grand soupçon que celui d'un tricheur à la vue d'une main chanceuse

Answer (score 1):

Il existe un proverbe qui illustre bien ceci :

> Méfiez-vous des méfiants.

Le sens est le même que dans l'exemple ; les gens ayant souvent tendance à croire qu'autrui va réagir comme eux-même, rencontrer une personne méfiante peut indiquer qu'elle pense que le reste du monde est autant pendable qu'elle.